# Using forked ProgressMonitorDialog in synchronized block

Tags: synchronization, jface

I am using a jface ProgressMonitorDialog to cache some data. This is being done in a synchronized block in order to not run into concurrency problems.

Strangely though, the synchronized block does not work if I am calling the ProgressMonitorDialog#run with the parameter fork=true.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Output:

```
start synchronization Thread[main,5,main]
start synchronization Thread[main,5,main]
finished synchronization Thread[main,5,main]
finished synchronization Thread[main,5,main]
```

Code:

```java
    private void test() {
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        SyncTest st = new SyncTest(shell);

        shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                st.doSmth();
            }
        });
        shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                st.doSmth();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class SyncTest {
        private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

        private Shell shell;

        public SyncTest(Shell shell) {
            this.shell = shell;
        }

        public void doSmth() {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                System.out.println("start synchronization " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
                try {
                    ProgressMonitorDialog pmd = new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell);
                    pmd.run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("finished synchronization " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Display.asyncExec` to put both the `doSmth` calls in to the list of runables that will be run in the UI thread as soon as `Display.readAndDispatch` is called.

So the first call to `doSmth` runs and enters the synchronized block.

It then calls `pmd.run` with fork true. This runs the runnable in a separate thread and also calls `Display.readAndDispatch` repeatedly to keep the UI thread responsive.

These `Display.readAndDispatch` calls will pick up the second call to `doSmth` - but you are still inside the synchronized block and still on the same UI thread so  `synchronized` does not block and you get the observed result.

If you want to run code in the background use a `Job` and specify a 'scheduling rule' to prevent any conflicting second job from running at the same time. If you have `setUser(true)` in the job it will display a progress dialog.